# PHP interface Gráfica

Tags: php, interface

Gostaria de saber como construir interfaces em um sistema desenvolvido em PHP de maneira simples e eficaz.
Gostaria de saber se existe algum tipo de Framework, caso exista qual o melhor para a construção de interfaces complexas.

Comment: A sua pergunta está ampla demais, poderia explicar que tipo de interface gráfica você quer fazer? O que você já fez? Quais tecnologias você pretende utilizar?

Comment: Quando se trabalha com web a principal forma de montar telas é com html, css e javascript que é bem diferente do desenvolvimento para desktops.

Comment: Exemplos de interface: Grid com rodapés que mostram o total de cada coluna
Progressbar nas células.
Grid com auto agrupamento de colunas..

Comment: O php é apenas o backend do sistema, para comportamentos dinâmicos procure por frameworks de javascript.

Comment: Tentei te ajudar mas você não está expressando de forma correta sua dúvida, primeiro pediu de interface gráfica, agora mudou o foco para melhor linguagem para consumir recursos via webservice. Faça uma pergunta específica e completa.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente em PHP é usado como linguagem web e para tal o desenvolvimento de telas é feito usando HTML e CSS, você pode achar vários tutoriais na net a respeito disso. Se for o caso recomendo o twitter bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) ou o Material design (http://www.google.com/design/)

Agora se for interface gráfica mesmo, tela de programas, tem o PHP-GTK que permite construir uma aplicação como um aplicativo desktop (http://www.php-gtk.com.br/)

Mas se for esse o caso, programação para desktop recomendo você escolher outra linguagem, utilize alguma linguagem .Net da vida, ou parta para o C/C++ que tem em sua estrutura muitas semelhanças com o PHP e vai te permitir utilizar outras bibliotecas como o Qt (http://www.qt.io/) que além de outros recursos provê bibliotecas para facilitar o desenvolvimento de interfaces.

Comment: A aplicação que pretendemos desenvolver devera conter interfaces ricas estilo desktop, gostaria de saber se php é a melhor opção para optarmos..

Comment: Se sua aplicação for web PHP pode ser considerado sim uma boa linguagem. Se for uma aplicação para desktop, como disse, utilize outra como .Net, C ou C++

Comment: Queria saber se a linguagem nos forneceria um grande suporte em:
Como realizar chamadas de webservice com autenticação com certificado digital;
Como gerar as classes php a partir de um arquivo XSD;
Como realizar assinaturas de arquivos xml digitalmente com certificado didgital;
Como converter um arquivo xml em objeto php com dados preenchidos;
Consumir serviços SOAP, JSON, automaticamente através dos WSDL fornecidos pelas SEFAZ;

Answer (score 1):

Para o desenvolvimento de interface em PHP você deverá fazer a mesma utilizando tecnologias web, como html, css e javascript. Neste contexto considero interessante você dar uma olhada no Bootstrap que se trata de um framework css. Com ele é possivel construir interfaces avançadas pois o mesmo contém vários templates de painéis espalhados pela web, como [este](http://daveismyname.com/free-bootstrap-admin-themes-bp#.VUIt1dJVhHw) ou [este outro](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/responsive-admin-templates.html) por exemplo.

Caso seja um sistema para desktop, sugiro ver sobre C# (ou qualquer outra linguagem .NET).